# Svcutil vs WS Policy

Tags: wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have a wsdl with following WS-Policy block:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MemberBindingPolicy">
    <wsp:All>
        <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V1Token11/>
                                <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:InitiatorToken>
                <sp:RecipientToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V1Token11/>
                                <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:RecipientToken>
                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Basic256Sha256/>
                        <sp:InclusiveC14N>http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</sp:InclusiveC14N>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                <sp:Layout>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Strict/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
                <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
        <sp:SignedParts>
            <sp:Body/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:Wss11>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss11>
    </wsp:All>
</wsp:Policy>
```

I run svc util and it returns following error:
An unsupported security policy assertion was detected during the security policy import 
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://xxxx.com']/wsdl:binding[@name='IssAuthSoapBinding']

Is there a workaround (in code, or not using svcutil at all)?
m.

Comment: According to [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c7b376f-b253-4131-95e5-57872e0837dc/error-an-unsupported-security-policy-assertion-was-detected-during-the-security-policy-import) removing the policy block before running svcutil would help. But I have no idea if WCF will be able to use the service or if the policy is incompatible with WCF.

Comment: Removing policy block helps generating code, but how can I implement required security policy manually (in code or config file)?